# How to merge the records from two queries each with unique fields having numeric data and avoiding doubling of numeric data

Tags: sql

I have two SQL queries.  They are very similar, actually identical with the exception of one where clause in each.  Each query sums a sale_amount field and aliases it as a different name as one is for sales and one is for adjustments.  I need to merge the records for both based on contract(c).id and transaction(t).line_id.  The problem i'm having is that when there are matching IDs and both queries matching have data in their respective dollar-based field, the dollar amount for the second query's field(sales) doubles.

I've seen other posts about this, but most seem to resolve the problem by using a LEFT JOIN.  I need to retain all data in both tables, regardless of a match as well(OUTER JOIN).  Below are the two individual queries.

```
// Query 1
SELECT c.id
     t.line_id
     t.date
     u.name
     a.name
     sum(t.sale_amount) as adjustments
FROM invoice i
JOIN contract c on c.contract_no = i.contract_no
JOIN transaction t on t.invoice_no = i.invoice_no
JOIN unit u on u.unit_no = t.unit_no
JOIN agency a on a.agency_no = i.agency_no
WHERE t.unit_no in (44)
     AND i.hard_invoice = 'Y'
     AND t.code in ('New', 'Edit')
     AND t.adjustment_no IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c.id, t.date, u.name, a.name, t.line_id

// Query 2
SELECT c.id
     t.line_id
     t.date
     u.name
     a.name
     sum(t.sale_amount) as sales
FROM invoice i
JOIN contract c on c.contract_no = i.contract_no
JOIN transaction t on t.invoice_no = i.invoice_no
JOIN unit u on u.unit_no = t.unit_no
JOIN agency a on a.agency_no = i.agency_no
WHERE t.unit_no in (44)
     AND i.hard_invoice = 'Y'
     AND t.code in ('New', 'Edit')
     AND t.adjustment_no IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id, t.date, u.name, a.name, t.line_id
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sybase however I'm querying it from within Qlikview.  I mention that as I've read outer join is not supported by Sybase however I have that capability in Qlikview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.id, t.line_id, t.date, u.name, a.name,
       sum(case when t.adjustment_no IS NOT NULL then t.sale_amount else 0 end) as adjustment,
       sum(case when t.adjustment_no IS NULL then t.sale_amount else 0 end) as sales
FROM invoice i JOIN
     contract c
     on c.contract_no = i.contract_no JOIN
     transaction t
     on t.invoice_no = i.invoice_no JOIN
     unit u
     on u.unit_no = t.unit_no JOIN
     agency a
     on a.agency_no = i.agency_no
WHERE t.unit_no in (44) AND
      i.hard_invoice = 'Y' AND
      t.code in ('New', 'Edit')
GROUP BY c.id, t.date, u.name, a.name, t.line_id;
```